# INDIRECT and CELL to dynamically get value from other worksheet, not working

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, worksheet

Trying to dynamically get cell value from worksheet in same workbook, depending on worksheet name in column E

```
=IF(E108<>"",INDIRECT(CELL("contents", E108)&"!"&F$1),"")
```

The formula set out above does not work.
I have evaluated the formula with the excel tool and have detailed each step below:

```
IF("P3672A"<>"",INDIRECT(CELL("contents", E108)&"!"&F$1),"")
IF(TRUE,INDIRECT(CELL("contents", E108)&"!"&F$1),"")
IF(TRUE,INDIRECT("P3672A"&"!"&F$1),"")
IF(TRUE,INDIRECT("P3672A!"&F$1),"")
IF(TRUE,INDIRECT("P3672A!"&"D9"),"")
IF(TRUE,INDIRECT("P3672A!D9"),"")
IF(TRUE,#REF!,"")
```

I can confirm that the cell D9 in worksheet P3672A does exist and contains a value.

Don't know why the formula does not work. Please can someone help with this

Comment: Try, =IF(E108<>"",INDIRECT(CELL("contents", E108)&"!F1"),"") or, =IF(E108<>"",INDIRECT(E108&"!F1"),"")

Comment: Wrap the tab name in `"'"` so if the tab name contains a space it would still work: `=IF(E108<>"",INDIRECT("'"&E108&"'!F1"),"")`